# Get A Spesific Field Of Class in a List

Tags: python

I have a list with name books and it stores some books like

```
book = Book("1","1984","20TL","George Orwell","1999","4","Drama")
book1 = Book("2", "Verwandlung", "25TL", "Franz Kafka", "2001", "5", "Drama")
book2 = Book("3", "Game of Thrones", "50TL", "George Martin", "2007", "5", "Drama")
```

They are all in the list

```
user.basket.books.append(book)
user.basket.books.append(book1)
user.basket.books.append(book2)
```

All i need is to get these first variables in a tuple. I mean, i need to get after one operation like that

> tuple = (1,2,3)

something like this but i dont know how. If it was c# i could use linq but i dont know in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write a generator expression to iterate over your sequence of `Book` and pull out that member (for example if it gets assigned to `self.num`)

```
book_nums = tuple(i.num for i in user.basket.books)
```